# Count cells with values in a column up to two above the active cell, excluding the header

Tags: excel, vba, count

I'm trying to count all the cells in a column that have values above the active cell excluding the header and excluding the cell immediately above the active cell.

For example if I have a column

> 1
>   5
>   4
>   N/A N/A
>   4
>   **current cell**

I want the current cell to equal 2. (Counting the 5 and 4, not the N/A N/A, not the cell above current cell, and not the first cell.)

The number of cells in the column will vary.

I want this for 260 consecutive columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub counter()

Dim col As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim cellcount As Integer

With ActiveCell
    col = .Column
    lastrow = .Row - 2
End With

cellcount = 0
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, col), Cells(lastrow, col))

    If IsError(cell) Then GoTo skipcell

    If cell.Value > 0 And IsNumeric(cell) Then cellcount = cellcount + 1

skipcell:

Next cell

ActiveCell = cellcount

End Sub
```

It takes the active cell and finds the selected colum and find the cell two above the active cell.

It then loops though the range adding to a counter each time it finds a value higher than "0"

As requested by OP in comments added in checks to ensure date in the cell is Numeric and that there is not a error (#N/A) value in the cell

Also requested is for this to span 260 columns in the same row. For this, use of a `for` loop is employed:

```
Sub counter()

Dim firstCol as Integer
dim lastCol as Integer

firstCol = 1 'You can change this value depending on your first column
             ' for example you might use ActiveCell.Column

lastCol = firstCol + 260

Dim col As Integer

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastRow = 6  ' Make this the actual last row of the data to include

Dim cellcount As Integer

for col = firstCol to lastCol

    cellcount = 0
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, col), Cells(lastrow, col))

        If IsError(cell) Then GoTo skipcell

        If cell.Value > 0 And IsNumeric(cell) Then cellcount = cellcount + 1

    skipcell:

    Next cell

    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow + 2, col) = cellcount

Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a column with a bunch of #N/A N/A values or #N/A Requesting Data and this is counting all of those. Can you modify it to count only the cells that contain values?

Comment: Perfect! Now I'd like to use that same logic and apply it to the next 260 cells in the row. (i have a data set with 260 columns I want to apply this to)

Comment: thanks for the edit @Will however I would stick with using active cell to determine both the last row & First column as other than knowing there are 260 columns of data it is not clear that there will only ever be 6 columns or that the data starts in column 1 (A) however I agree with your comment on your own answer - between us we have now given RicardoBarrios everything he needs to edit the code to fit his criteria

Comment: @Will - Just thought I would mention I almost altered your edit to move all the variable declarations back to the top - since that is how I have always done it, but then I re-read the code and found it is actually easier to follow, You may have converted me to a new way of declaring :)

Comment: Haha nice one. I tend to try and declare variables as close to where they are used as possible, so long as they're not in loops. Then they can be initialised with values on the next line if possible! Happy coding :)

Comment: Just seen your previous comment too @EdHunter, agreed my edit is not the most flexible as it involves diving into the macro every time the sheet layout changes a little! However, I wasn't about to dive into an explanation about `.find`, `.end` or `.usedrange`!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the number of cells in the column will vary, so how do i incorporate your note "Make this the actual last row of the data to include" when the last row of the data changes every time I run it?

Comment: @RicardoBarrios You have been provided the code to do what you have asked assuming each column contains the same amount of data. Please could I ask that you mark this answer as correct and if you have further questions please post a new question.
If each of your 260 columns has a different number of rows in it then you need to state that clearly in your new question.

Comment: How do I mark it as correct? Sorry this is my first question on this site.

Comment: @RicardoBarrios Click the tick mark at the top left of the answer

Comment: Thank you @Ed! Please let me know if you can assist at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191216/i-need-to-modify-code-to-count-a-variable-number-of-rows-in-a-column

Answer (score 1):

Why does this have to be VBA code?

It is very simple to do in a cell formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"<>0")-2
```

This counts all the cells in the given range (`A1:A5`) which are not equal to zero. Since you know you want to remove the header row and one row above, subtract 2 from the answer. Of course, this the same as

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A4,"<>0")
```

If you want to use this in VBA then look into `WorksheetFunction`:

```
Dim myCount As Integer
myCount = WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A4"),"<>0")
```

Then insert `myCount` into the sheet

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A6").value = myCount
```

Comment: My range will change on different data sets. Can this be modified to count the non #N/A N/A values in the entire column above the current cell except for the cell above it and the header?

Comment: @RicardoBarrios you can use the `COUNTIFS` (plural) function to add multiple conditions, for example `"=NOT(ISNA("A1:A6"))"` to check for non-#N/A values. Are you planning on using the cell formula or VBA?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in VBA so I can replicate without using cell references since the number of cells in the column will change. @Ed's code worked but now I'm trying to apply it to the next 260 rows in the spreadsheet. See above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: At this stage you should really just mark Ed's answer as accepted and open a new question. Your initial question included very little of what you already tried and now you are asking for complete code you can just copy. Aside from this, I've edited Ed's answer to complete your request.